# How to open a file only for appending in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I want a try/except clause to take different actions if a file has not yet been created, versus if something's going to be appended to it.  I've tried writing the following code:

```
try:
    print("Appended!")
    dip_line = "|".join(DATA)
    dip_line = "|" + dip_line + "\n"
    with open(OUTPUT_LOCATION, "a") as filey: # also tried "a+", no luck
        filey.write(dip_line)
except:
    print("Created!")
    DATA.insert(0, SYS_COMMENT)
    dip_line = "|".join(DATA)
    dip_line += "\n"
    with open(OUTPUT_LOCATION, "w") as filey:
        filey.write(dip_line)
```

How can I ensure that the except clause gets run when no [OUTPUT_LOCATION] exists?  Thanks for your consideration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the file in `r+` (read-write) mode instead so it would raise an exception if the file does not already exist, and then use the [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) method to point the file position to the end of the file for appending:

```
with open(OUTPUT_LOCATION, "r+") as filey:
    filey.seek(0, 2)
    filey.write(dip_line)
```